# Something goes somewhere

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I'm interested in using the construction **something goes somewhere** and want to know if we always use to mean that something should fit somewhere, is intended to be somewhere or is meant to add up to some place?

1. Imagine somebody fixing something, "**Okay this goes here, and this goes here. But where does this go?**"
2. Imagine somebody doing a puzzle, "**Okay this part goes here and this one should go here, I guess.**"
3. Imagine somebody assembling a computer, "**Right, this part goes in here and we can close the panel.**"

Are all these usages right?

Comment: I'm sure some people have sometimes said things like *This bit goes here, that bit goes there, and the other bit just **goes*** - meaning the third bit can just ***go / be thrown away*** (because we don't need it). But it would probably be said with a smile, since it would effectively be a facetious "zeugma / syllepsis" usage.

Answer (score 3):

Go has dozens of definitions, including "to belong; have a place". All three of these constructions sound right to me, and I've seen all of them used before.